# convert List<Object> to List<Map> with 2 keys using RxJava

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, rx-java2

I have a list of objects and I want to convert it to a list of maps that have a 2 keys.

**code example**

```
// list of books (objects)
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
books.add(new Book(1, 6));
books.add(new Book(2, 2));
books.add(new Book(3, 9));
books.add(new Book(4, 18));

List<Map<String, Object>> booksMap = Collections.emptyList();

// convert list into list of maps using regular for-loop
// map structure with 2 keys
for (Book book : books) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("id", book.getId());
    map.put("quantity", book.getQuantity());

    booksMap.add(map);
}
```

So each object (book) have to be converted to a Map which hold a 2 keys.

**My question is how to do it using RxJava**

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I got confused when I focus on the **toMap** operator in RxJava which return a Map that holds only one key and keep trying to reach the same result as the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to subscribe to an Observable created with the `fromIterable` convenience method which receives your list of books, afterwards it will emit the items one by one, then every item transformed into a Map and finally group them up in a list using the `toList` operator.

```
    Observable.fromIterable(books)
    .map(new Function<Book, Map<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> apply(Book book) throws Exception {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("id", book.id);
            map.put("quantity", book.quantity);
            return map;
        }
    })
    .toList()
    .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List<Map<String, Object>> mapsList) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(mapsList);
        }
    });
```